# Laravel 5. Как добавить таблицу в БД не затрагивая данные в других таблицах

Tags: laravel5, миграция

Проект Laravel 5.5.
           Нужно добавить дополнительную таблицу в БД сохранив данные в других таблицах.
Повторный посев данных (seeds) после применения

```
"php artisan migrate:rollback"
```

не подходит, так как данных столько, что повторный посев затянется на несколько дней.

Можно ли добавить таблицу так, чтобы никаким образом не затрагивать те таблицы, что уже существуют?

Answer (score 0):

Это оказалось проще пареной репы, 
"php artisan migrate" после создания таблицы не затрагивает другие таблицы.